# How to run MathExprPowerModel in gem5?

Tags: module, gem5

I want to run `MathExprPowerModel` file in `gem5`.
After building process, I type the command to run.
But it is not working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDu4g.png)
I want to run the file and hope to get power profiling of a system.
Thanks!

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean exactly? What happens? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: In addition to what Wodin said: provide your full gem5 CLI and gem5 revision. Also try to GDB step debug gem5, and activate `DPRINTF` logs with `--debug-flags`. With all that, if it still does not work, ping the mailing list. Also try a Git blame and CC specific people if no one replies in a few days.

Comment: Command line : build/X86/gem5.opt src/sim/power/MathExprPowermodel.py

Comment: And it shows error like this :
Traceback (most recent call last):
AssertionError: Simobject PowerModelState already present